# FBOAuth Module Drupal 7 to 6 Convertion

Tags: social-network

I've been trying out this codes from this blog, and tried a couple of snippets and my trials on the codes but have no luck at the moment.

This blog has (http://www.grasmash.com/article/connecting-facebook-drupal-easy-way) the following functions:

```
/** 
 * Implements hook_fboauth_user_properties_alter(). 
 */ 
function grasmash_fboauth_user_properties_alter(&$properties) { 
  // Allow the location property to be mapped to Addressfield typed fields.   
  $properties['location']['field_types'][] = 'addressfield'; 
}
```

which this hook is available in D6

```
/**
 * Implements hook_fboauth_field_convert_info().
 */ 

function grasmash_fboauth_field_convert_info_alter(&$convert_info) { 
  $convert_info += array( 'addressfield' => array( 
    'label' => t('Address Field'), 
    'callback' => 'grasmash_fboauth_field_convert_location', 
    ), 
  ); 
}
```

This is never fired up, and seems i cannot find the hook in D6

```
/** 
 * Facebook data conversion function. 
 * Converts an incoming Facebook location (which is an object) into an array compatible with the addressfield module. 
*/ 
function grasmash_fboauth_field_convert_location($facebook_property_name, $fbuser, $field, $instance) { 
  $value = NULL; 
  if ($field['type'] == 'addressfield' && isset($fbuser->location) && module_exists('geocoder')) { 
    $geodata = geocoder('google', $fbuser->location->name); 
    foreach ($geodata->data['geocoder_address_components'] as $key => $components) { 
      switch($components->types[0]) { 
        // Set city. 
        case 'locality': 
          $value['locality'] = $components->short_name; 
        break; 
        // Set state. 
        case 'administrative_area_level_1': 
          $value['administrative_area'] = $components->short_name; 
        break; 
        // Set country. 
        case 'country': 
          $value['country'] = $components->short_name; 
        break; 
       } 
     } 
   } 
   return $value; 
}
```

This one is firedup when the second function is firedup, but the logic inside of this doesnt matter as long as $fbuser is available.

In totality my goal is to have access of the $fbuser after the user successfully connect to Facebook.